# Is "Brainy Smurf" a correct example for a "Klugscheißer"?

Tags: meaning

Brainy Smurf/Schlaubi Schlumpf is a pseudo-clever guy, did I got the point of the word *Klugscheißer* correctly?

Comment: Yes, I'd say so. But not because they are "pseudo clever" but rather because they feel the need to express their cleverness as often as possible.

Comment: @AndreasT: I'd say, this is enough for an answer... I'd write one, but I'd rather say almost the same as you and don't want to take credit for your answer...Would you write one yourself?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Yes, calling that character a "Klugscheißer" would be a fair description in my opinion. Although the reason is less about them being "pseudo clever" but rather that they feel the need to express their cleverness as often as possible.

"Smart-ass" is a good English equivalent.

Comment: Good answer... I specially like your reference to "pseudo clever", as Schlaubi Schlumpf in fact is quite clever and knows a lot... what makes him a "Klugscheißer" is exactly what you pointed out.